# Test a function inside another function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hello I was trying to test a function inside another function that needs a parameter from outside the second function.

```js
export const DetailsView = ({ intl, object, onClose }) => {
  // some code
  const getIsLogbookAllowed = () => {
    return object && object.driver;
  };

  // more code
};
```

Trying to test this function `onLogbookReportModalClose`, but I think when I do instance the variable object is not read it and it converted as null.

Testing

```
test('should return \'false\' when there is no driver', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<DetailsView {...props} />)
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    expect(instance.getIsLogbookAllowed()).toBe(true)
}
```

Error:

> TypeError: instance.getIsLogbookAllowed is not a function

Any suggestion?

Comment: where is getIsLogbookAllowed?

Comment: Where is the function used? Could you test that the component renders correctly/passes the correct props to a child component based on the result of the function instead of _directly_ testing the function itself?

Comment: @etarhan yes with another way

Answer (score 0):

That's because `getIsLogBookAllowed` isn't a property of the component's instance, it's undefined, thus not a function.

What you should do is something like this:

```
export class DetailsView extends Component {
  getIsLogBookAllowed = () => this.props.object && this.props.object.driver;

  render() {
    return <JSX />
  }
}
```

This way the function becomes part of the instance of the component, you could replace classes with functions, that'd work too.